# How can i find out the respective values of 'object' and 'method' ,they are arguments of the constructor System.MulticastDelegate?

Tags: sos, .net

I decompiled the delegate using .Net Reflector.i find it inherit from System.MulticastDelegate
.And the constructor of System.MulticastDelegate has two arguments that are 'object' and 'method'.But using sos.dll,how can i get the specific value of them?i am a newer,i want to see the specific value(their Type belong to Value Type.In my opinion,all object are composed of Value Type)

Answer (score 0):

1 - To find method arguments using SOS, run !clrstack -a.  Alternatively, you can use sosex.dll and run !mdv or !mk -a.  You can also find objects on the stack using !sos.dso or !sosex.mdso.  If you have an instance of System.MulticastDelegate and want to examine the fields, then use !sos.do (!DumpObj) or !sosex.mdt.

2 - NOT all objects are derived from ValueType.  All objects are actually derived from System.Object.  All types that derive from System.ValueType are known as "value types".
In fact, even System.ValueType is derived from System.Object, but they are treated as special by the runtime.